# Does this graph support an assumption of homoscedasticity?

Tags: regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity, gamlss

[image]Does this graphics support the assumption of homoscedasticity?

[image]

Comment: The [same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/337262/7224) was asked and answered on this forum two years ago.

Comment: @Xi'an the plot shown in the question to which you link has many other features though and so, even though reading it might help the OP, I do not think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @mdewey: it is impossible to tell the OP's intents given the current question is just made of a graph.

Comment: These are two different graphs from the previous question, that is, another different analysis. Could you help me, please?

Comment: my question is that of the other one you sent the link to, but the graph is different, and his analysis is also

Comment: Those two graphs are not the same so which one is your question about?

Comment: Both graphics !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first graph (residuals versus predicted) could be interpreted to show a variance systematically increasing with predicted value. If that is important or not depends on your goals, but it might be. I would maybe try a model where residual variance is modeled as a function of expectation $\mu$, in R such models can for instance be fitted with the package `gamlss`.

For an example see [Are there better approaches than the weighted mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495811/are-there-better-approaches-than-the-weighted-mean/495845#495845).